# Joi custom error for each validation option

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I have `Joi` schema and want to specify a custom error message for each of the options.

Example of my schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string()
      .min(5).error(() => 'first message')
      .max(25).error(() => 'second message')
      .required().error(() => 'third message')
)}
```

At the moment this validation works in such way: if whatever of the option is invalid only third message appears.

Expected behavior - error message appears according to which option is invalid (as default Joi behavior, but with my custom error message).

Thanks in regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
title: Joi.string()
  .min(5)
  .max(25)
  .required()
  .messages({
  "string.min": "first msg",
  "string.max": "second msg",
  "any.empty":"third msg"
      })
  })
```

These is the best way to show custom error messages

Comment: This is much better and clean way than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For my situation I just found such solution:

```js
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    title: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(25)
      .required()
      .error((errors) => {
        return errors.map(error => {
          switch (error.type) {
            case "string.min":
              return { message: "first msg" };
            case "string.max":
              return { message: "second msg" };
            case "any.empty":
              return { message: "third msg" };
          }
        }
        )
      })
```

Seems not the best one, as it cause too many code, especialy if you have big form, hovewer it works as I desire.